# c# RawPrintHelper. How can i send a BOLD command

Tags: c#, printing, epson, bold

I have this piece of code to send some text lines to a dot matrix ticket printer.

```
public static void PrintInvoice(string PrinterName, Ticket ticket)
{
    string s = string.Empty;
    string COMMAND = Convert.ToString((char)29) + "V" + Convert.ToString((char)66) + Convert.ToString((char)0);
    foreach (string k in ticket.Data)
    {
        s = s + k + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    s = s + COMMAND;
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(PrinterName, s);
}
```

It works fine but i need to set BOLD or SIZED font in one of the lines.
I've searched everywhere but i couldnt find the way for sending a BOLD o SIZE command to RawPrinterHelper.

I would appreciate any help.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if RawPrintHelper is your only choice; I was able to locate [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94967169-a9ee-45db-9c8a-acd6f173680d/rawprinthelper-for-bold-font?forum=csharpgeneral) which uses PrintDocument instead and allows Bold functionality.